# How to call an Activity method from another class?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a WebView in my activity, which have a JSInterface :

```
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(mWebView, this), "interfaceWebsite");
```

When I call a function in my interface, I would like to see some Views (Textview/Button) modified.

```
public void changeStep(int newStep){
                step = newStep;
                tvStep.setText("Etape "+step);
                step_info = getString(R.string.step3_info);

        }
    }
```

step_info works (my options menu change), it's just a string var, but not my TextView, it throw VM aborting.

I call the function this way (where addWebsiteActivity is "this" in the code above) :

```
addWebsiteActivity.changeStep(step);
```

Is this possible to do that in a proper way ?

Thanks

---

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Taht's why I can call changeStep from JSInterface but I can inside my activity class... How can I do that then ?

---

And the solution is...

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {

                 step = newStep;
                 tvStep.setText("Etape "+step);
                 step_info = getString(R.string.step3_info);



            }
        });
```

Like this it knows it's a code for the main thread. But it's strange Eclipse throw me VM aborting exept that the explicit error above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`changeStep` method must be called inside UI thread. You can achieved this with `runOnUiThread`:

```
addWebsiteActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        changeStep(step);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

change step to newStep in your code

Comment: I edited my post, it was a wrong code, I know why setText() it not working (see above), but how can I tell to my activity to set text of my TextView without call a function... ?

Comment: u mean without calling a function like textView.setText(someText);